# Pandas Delete Data After Last Space

Tags: python, pandas

I have strings that will always contain one space, sometimes two and conceivably three. Eg

```
Run 8890
Test Run GoLive
Test Run Fall Over
```

I want to delete all data after the last space. I had thought the following would work but it throws an error:

```
result['t1'] = result['t1'].str.rsplit(' ')[-1]
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to **delete** all data after the last space rather than **retain** data after the last space, you could use:

```
result['t1'] = result['t1'].str.rsplit(' ').str[:-1].str.join(' ')
```

Result:

```
              t1
0            Run
1       Test Run
2  Test Run Fall
```

Answer (score 2):

use:

```
result['t1']=result['t1'].str.rsplit(' ').str[:-1].apply(' '.join)
```

Output of `result`:

```
    t1
0   Run
1   Test Run
2   Test Run Fall
```

Comment: Thanks Anurag. This deletes everything before the space rather than after it.

Comment: Updated answer...Kindly have a look **:)**

Answer (score 1):

***1st solution:*** With [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) function of Pandas you could try following.

```
df['column'].str.extract(r'(.*)(?=\s+)')
```

***Explanation:*** using `str.extract` function of Pandas and using regex to match everything till last space in value in single capturing group.

---

---

***2nd solution:*** With [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) function of Pandas try following:

```
df['column'].str.replace(r'\s+\S+$','')
```

***Explanation:*** Using `str.replace` using regex to replace everything from last space(s) with non-spaces values till end with NULL.

Output will be as follows:

```
0              Run
1         Test Run
2    Test Run Fall
```